# HttpServlet special character issue

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I have java application which has httpservlet class. This class has doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) method as common servlet class. Nothing special.
This servlet waits for requests from other applications which I can't change and see. 
This applications put token param as paramName to request. Token could contain different symbols and numbers.
And I have a problem: sometimes tokens comes in this format token=cc%7C342084%7C7957 but when I use it in my servlet it already cc|342084|7957
I suppose, it's because my servlet see %7c and thinks that it |. How could I prevent this? I need token to be the same as it comes. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using `String paramName = new String(request.getParameter("paramName").getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

Comment: @SudhirOjha, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried and received the same.